# How can I detect source errors for a video rendered using React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html5-video

I have a react component subclass which renders a video:

```
render() {
  return (
    <video id="video">
      <source src={this.props.src} type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  );
}
```

I need to attach an event listener for the `error` event to the video source some time after it's created but before it's rendered. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't want to dynamically attach the event. Instead just  have the event on it and have some if condition in the event.

If you really want to attach it dynamically then do:

```
<video id="video" onError={this.state.someCondition ? myFunc : null}>
  <source src={this.props.src} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Or use `this.props.someCondition` if you are passing the condition down from the parent.

If your condition isn't in the state or props then it will need to be.

If this isn't what you want then post more context please. Sounds like you want the [`componentWillMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) function